# how to make a trigger to prevent any UPDATE?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

iam trying to make trigger to prevent any edit in the data in my database  , so not to a specific table  but all tables . so  it is under no circumstances possible to modify data that is already in the database.

any hint .

Comment: Just do not grant `update` privilege. The same for `insert` and `delete` as they are data modifications also.

Comment: Why would you use a trigger rather than just setting permissions appropriately?

Comment: @dougp , Because I want to show the message "Sorry, you cannot modify the data" 
and  that cant by grant

Comment: What RDBMS?  Doesn't yours tell you basically that?  SQL Server says `The UPDATE permission was denied on the object 'TableName', database 'DatabaseName', schema 'dbo'.`  That seems pretty clear.

Comment: PostgreSQL  @RBarryYoung

Comment: The response to the user is not the database error message, but something that your application generates. Use permissions.

Comment: As has been said by the others, you really don't want this. REVOKE the permissions, that's the standard and proven way to protect data.